# Creating an external vSwitch on Hyper-V (on Windows 10) kills upload speed

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, hyper-v

I recently decided to give Hyper-V a try and see if I can replace my VirtualBox setup with something more "windows-native".  Hyper-V was fairly easy to set up. However, as soon as I create an external vSwitch to connect to the internet (on my wifi), the upload speed of my laptop is killed (sub 1Mps)!!! This renders my windows practically useless. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Update: After wrestling with various configurations with no luck, I googled the issue some more and came across this very useful post: [Creating an external virtual switch on Hyper-V causes host to experience very slow networking](https://superuser.com/questions/1371759/creating-an-external-virtual-switch-on-hyper-v-causes-host-to-experience-very-sl/1375670#1375670)

And more specifically, this solved my issue:

- Set “Recv Segment Coalescing (IPv4)” to “Disabled”
- Set “Recv Segment Coalescing (IPv6)” to “Disabled”