# Hyper V running on windows 10 machine can't see microsoft for windows update

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I have a box that is running windows 10 (most recent release) and it's a hyper-V host to another machine that is running windows 10.

The host machine is a work laptop with zscalar, webroot, and is part of a domain managed by microsoft intune.  It has no issues with windows update or anything like that.

The hyper-V VM uses the default network switch with default settings.  it has no trouble accessing the internet except for windows update, for some reason that seems completely blocked.  I've been able to disable zscalar, but the issue still happens so i know that isn't the problem.  If i change the default switch to an external switch, then it actually works, but the internet is VERY slow (now for both the host and the VM.  Same issue as [Hyper-V External network switch kills my host's network performance](https://superuser.com/questions/1266248/hyper-v-external-network-switch-kills-my-hosts-network-performance)).  Deleting the external switch fixes this slowness issue.

Is this something anyone else has seen or dealt with?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author is attempting to bypass an enterprising network configuration.

Comment: I'm not trying to bypass.  I'm trying to use exactly the same network on my host.  My host can do a windows update, but the VM cannot.  The VM should have the same access as the host, right?

Comment: If this is a Active Directory (Intune) domain it would not have access unless the VM joined the domain.

Comment: That's what i'm trying to figure out then, if there is any other way other than making it join the domain in order to see microsoft windows update.  For various reasons that's not a great option for us.  My sys admin was actually asking me if i could find a workaround, or at least confirm that Intune was the actual issue here

Comment: It is indeed your issue.